# Import a scalar from Excel to Gams

Tags: excel, gams-math

I need to import a scalar (say d=240) number from excel to GAMS.

```
parameter d;
$CALL GDXXRW mydata.xlsx par=d  rng=Sheet1!a1
$GDXIN mydata.gdx
$LOAD d
$GDXIN
display d;
```

But never display the correct value. Always d=0. I can import a matrix from excel to GAMS easily, but I can not import a scalar number.

Comment: I tried using cdim=1 and/or rdim=1. But nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this issue by explicitly giving gdxxrw the dimension of the parameter (here 0).

```
parameter d;
$CALL GDXXRW mydata.xlsx par=d  rng=Sheet1!a1 dim=0
$GDXIN mydata.gdx
$LOAD d
$GDXIN
display d;
```

PS: if you had looked at mydata.gdx, you'd have seen that d was 0 there. Thus, the problem was with gdxxrw.